# Listen to afterWrite of a job running inside a step

Tags: spring-batch

This is my step config:

```
@Bean
Step processEnrollment(@Lazy Job enrollmentProcessor) {
    return this.steps.get("processEnrollment")
        .job(enrollmentProcessor)
        .launcher(this.jobLauncher)
        .parametersExtractor(DEFAULT_PARAM_EXTRACTOR)
        .listener(/*StepExecutionListener*/)
        .build();
}
```

My problem is that `.listener()` only accepts step execution listeners. Is there any way to register writer listeners, for example? I don't want to couple the "internal" job with this listener.

Comment: Where is your writer in above code? Is that writer part of `Job enrollmentProcessor` ?

Comment: The writer is part of enrollmentProcessor and I want to listen to it outside but StepBuilderHelper.listener() only accepts step execution listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap a complete job into a step, you cannot register a chunk, read, or write-listener.

The step simply wraps a job and has no clue what is going on inside the job. It just knows when it begins and when it ends; the listeners aren't propagated to the child elements.
It's the same reason, why you cannot register a chunk, read, or write listener on a job.

If you want to register a write listener, you have to do this on the appropriate step(s) of your enrollmentProcessor-job.